# how to access embedded pdf file in web page

Tags: c#, pdf, html

When I download a url that has an embedded pdf file, I can access all the page html, just not the pdf file itself.  I've tried HttpWebRequest, WebClient, HtmlAgilityPack, memorystreams, and more.  Not sure what path can work.  Here's as close as I got.  Any help is appreciated.

```
string url = "http://emaps.emapsplus.com/rdl/MadisonCoAl/MadisonCoAl.aspx?showimg=yes&pid=1701013003029000";

byte[] result;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);
using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

            } while (count != 0);

            result = memoryStream.ToArray();

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\testpdf.pdf", result);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ones really tricky since it isn't actually a pdf file that is being downloaded. Your code would work if it was a normal pdf. This is a webpage that runs some javascript that posts back to itself to generate the pdf.

I have the answer to your immediate problem but you may have a long road ahead of you if you need to do this for many files. To get this to work I ran the page through [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to get the post string that it was posting back to itself and then I used C# to emulate that process and save the result as a pdf.

This works great but the problem is that without that manual step of getting the post string via Fiddler you would basically have to create your own web browser that understands all the javascript codes and execute them to find out how the string is generated.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sURL = "http://emaps.emapsplus.com/rdl/MadisonCoAl/MadisonCoAl.aspx?showimg=yes&pid=1701013003029000";
            string sSource = "";

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        do
                        {
                            count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                        } while (count != 0);

                        sSource = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSource))
            {
                const string sQuoteString = "\"";   // If the values are not being found it could be because the markup is being output with single quotes change this variable from "\"" to "'" in that case
                const string sViewStateString = "__VIEWSTATE";
                const string sEventValidationString = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                const string sValueString = "value=" + sQuoteString;

                Int32 nIndex1 = sSource.IndexOf(sViewStateString);
                Int32 nIndex2 = default(Int32);
                bool bFoundValues = false;
                string sViewState = "";
                string sEventValidation = "";

                // Look for the view state and event validation tags and grab the values
                // Without these values we cannot continue

                if (nIndex1 > -1)
                {
                    nIndex2 = sSource.IndexOf(sValueString, nIndex1);

                    if (nIndex2 > -1)
                    {
                        nIndex1 = sSource.IndexOf(sQuoteString, nIndex2 + sValueString.Length);

                        if (nIndex1 > -1)
                        {
                            sViewState = sSource.Substring(nIndex2 + sValueString.Length, nIndex1 - nIndex2 - sValueString.Length);
                            nIndex1 = sSource.IndexOf(sEventValidationString);

                            if (nIndex1 > -1)
                            {
                                nIndex2 = sSource.IndexOf(sValueString, nIndex1);

                                if (nIndex2 > -1)
                                {
                                    nIndex1 = sSource.IndexOf(sQuoteString, nIndex2 + sValueString.Length);

                                    if (nIndex1 > -1)
                                    {
                                        sEventValidation = sSource.Substring(nIndex2 + sValueString.Length, nIndex1 - nIndex2 - sValueString.Length);
                                        bFoundValues = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (bFoundValues == true)
                {
                    Int32 nTimeout = 30;
                    HttpWebRequest oRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(sURL).AbsoluteUri) as HttpWebRequest;
                    string sPostData = "__EVENTTARGET=btnPageLoad&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sViewState) + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sEventValidation) + "&hdnLoaded=false&ReportViewer1%24ctl03%24ctl00=&ReportViewer1%24ctl03%24ctl01=&ReportViewer1%24ctl11=&ReportViewer1%24ctl12=standards&ReportViewer1%24AsyncWait%24HiddenCancelField=False&ReportViewer1%24ToggleParam%24store=&ReportViewer1%24ToggleParam%24collapse=false&ReportViewer1%24ctl09%24ClientClickedId=&ReportViewer1%24ctl08%24store=&ReportViewer1%24ctl08%24collapse=false&ReportViewer1%24ctl10%24VisibilityState%24ctl00=Error&ReportViewer1%24ctl10%24ScrollPosition=&ReportViewer1%24ctl10%24ReportControl%24ctl02=&ReportViewer1%24ctl10%24ReportControl%24ctl03=&ReportViewer1%24ctl10%24ReportControl%24ctl04=100";
                    byte[] oPostDataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sPostData);

                    oRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0";
                    oRequest.Timeout = nTimeout * 1000;
                    oRequest.Method = "POST";
                    oRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    oRequest.ContentLength = oPostDataBuffer.Length;

                    using (Stream oRequestStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        oRequestStream.Write(oPostDataBuffer, 0, oPostDataBuffer.Length);
                        oRequestStream.Close();
                    }

                    HttpWebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                    if (oResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        // Error

                        MessageBox.Show(oResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Status is OK

                        byte[] oBuffer = null;
                        byte[] oFile = null;

                        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream oMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {

                                oBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(1024);

                                while (oBuffer.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    oMemoryStream.Write(oBuffer, 0, oBuffer.Length);
                                    oBuffer = reader.ReadBytes(1024);
                                }

                                oFile = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(oMemoryStream.Length)))];
                                oMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                                oMemoryStream.Read(oFile, 0, oFile.Length);
                            }
                        }

                        using (FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream("C:\\testpdf.pdf", FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            oFileStream.Write(oFile, 0, oFile.Length);
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("PDF downloaded to C:\\testpdf.pdf");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot find the __VIEWSTATE and/or __EVENTVALIDATION variables.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find source code for original url.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

There is most likely some kind of session involved with the post data and it already timed out before you were able to test it. Therefore this means we have to get even more creative. I will admit this has been a bit of trial and error and this code is really tailored to this one url and may or may not work for other pdfs on the same website. By comparing the sPostData string I posted earlier with a new one I just grabbed now by running the website through the Fiddler proxy, I discovered that only 2 of the many variables that are posted have changed. Both of these 2 variables are available in the html source code that can be generated from your original C# code. So all we do is a little string manipulation and grab a copy of those variables and **THEN** do the original code that I posted. See? We are working together now! This updated code should now work every time without giving the 500 internal server error message.

**NOTE:** Because we are posting data that has not been properly encoded for the web, we must include a reference to system.web to gain access to the urlencode method. To do this you need to:

1. Right click on "References" in the "Solution Explorer" and choose "Add Reference"
2. Click into "Assemblies" on the left and find "System.Web" in the "Framework" section or use the search box on the far right
3. Put a check next to "System.Web" and click "OK"

Here's code to streamline capturing the postback data

```
        var postData = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
        foreach (var input in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@type='hidden']"))
        {
            var name = input.GetAttributeValue("name", "");
            name = Uri.EscapeDataString(name);
            var value = input.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
            value = Uri.EscapeDataString(value);
            if (name == "__EVENTTARGET")
            {
                value = "btnPageLoad";
            }

            postData.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", name, value));
        }

        // Use StringBuilder for concatenation 
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(postData[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < postData.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("&");
            sb.Append(postData[i]);
        }
        var postBody = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you!  When I run this, I get the following error:The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. on line HttpWebResponse oResponse = .....  Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer along with some updated information about why it didn't work for you earlier. Hopefully it works this time!

Comment: That's great Tom and your new code to capture postback data is certainly a lot cleaner than mine! Also since this worked for you please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer (it will turn green) so that others know you found a solution to your question!

Comment: I was wondering how to accept the answer, clicking on the up arrow told me I didn't have enough points to vote.  I really appreciate your help.  Also, I don't want to take credit for my streamlining the code, I got that from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPDFPath= "FULL PATH";
  WebClient User = new WebClient();
                Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(sPDFPath);
                if (FileBuffer != null)
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
                }
```